# Mapping Data Flows Error The stream is either not connected or column is unavailable

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a meta-data driven pipeline and a mapping data flow to load my data. When I try to run this pipeline, I get the following error.

```
{"message":"at Derive 'TargetSATKey'(Line 42/Col 26): Column 'PersonVID' not found. The stream is either not connected or column is unavailable. Details:at Derive 'TargetSATKey'(Line 42/Col 26): Column 'PersonVID' not found. The stream is either not connected or column is unavailable","failureType":"UserError","target":"Data Vault Load","errorCode":"DFExecutorUserError"}
```

When I debug the mapping data flow, all the components in the data flow work as intended.

I guess that my source connection parameters aren't flowing through properly. Below is an email of my source connection

[image: Source connection]

[image: Pipeline error]

Please let me know if you have any thoughts and questions

Comment: Please check the schema of SATSource, import again. Derived column read the column from source.

Comment: Hi @LeonYue, It should all be derived through meta-data. I have tried to recheck everything but I still get the same error or it errors at a different pipeline. It works when   I debug it and pass in the variables manually

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolution to my problem. The error was the data being passed in was a string but when the variable was unpacked my variable value didn't have a quote around it. Putting in the quotes fixed it.

For example

```
'BusinessEntityID'
```

Please let me know if there are any questions